# How to use python to retrieve text from mouse double click

Tags: python

I am interested in how to retrieve text with python from the selected content when mouse double clicked, such as on web page or on document. I hope someone can help me.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Not quite sure I get the question, but if double-click, or whatever, happens in the browser, there is no way the server can know about it unless you use JavaScript to intercept the event and send even details to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is a server side language, it does not handle dom event. 
For dom events use javascript